# In chemfig how do I notate an empty bond?

Tags: chemfig

In certain contributions to resonant structures of some compounds there is not a bond between two separate parts and so the total bond is less than one. How would I position the parts as if they were attached by a bond but not actually put a bond symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I'm sure you know when you have used `chemfig` already the bonds have optional arguments. The manual says:

> **6 Customization of bonds**
>
> There is a fifth and last optional argument for bonds which is found
>   after the fourth comma:
>
> ```
> [,,,,<tikz code>]
> ```

This means all you have to do is adding the TikZ code for not-drawing:

```
\chemfig{-C-[,,,,draw=none]C-}
```

[image]